# How to capture direct query and Linq to sql calls to database from my system

Tags: performance, http, testing, tcp, fiddler

I am able to capture WCF HTTP calls made from my system with the help of fiddler and i hope you understood my question.

I want to capture calls to made to SQL Server by LINQ to Sql and Direct query expression from system, i was on google for this but dint get any help, is there any tool available or something that can help me to capture.

let me know if my you dont understand my question.

Thanks
Syed

Comment: If I understood you want to see queries executed by/from LINQ. There is a tool within MS SQL Server: **SQL Profiler**. You'll see all executed queries (and many other things about them).

Comment: i know sql profiler, it gives query which executed on that instance, but it will not specify who has executed this query, i mean by LINQ or direct query expression.

if a call goes to sql server want to identify whether it is executed by Linq or direct query.

Comment: Something like [LINQ To SQL Debug Visualizer](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx)?

Comment: Adriano thanks for your reply, 
 let me explain my issue in detail for you, as you know wcf calls are http, it can be capture by fiddler, but calls to sql server goes through tcp and fiddler will not capture such calls.

suppose X functionality has 3 calls to wcf, In 2 places linq is been used and 5 places direct query is executing, i have code in front me but cant figure out each call from code because its very complex, my question is, some code or tool has to tell me that if you perform X functionality these number of calls made of these types.

Comment: The best way I have found to do this is with IntelliTrace. See:
[Jaliya's Blog](https://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2012/09/visual-studio-intellitrace.html?m=1)
[MS Post #1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/view-historical-application-state?view=vs-2022)
[Azure DevOps laps](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/devopsserver/debugging/)